# How show tooltip In Flutter using charts_flutter package

Tags: flutter, charts

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter For charts in my app. I want to show tooltip when I press point in PointsLineChart.

Any way to show tooltip?

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with this for an hour and finally found a solution in a [github issue](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/58#issuecomment-488695645) I modified the code a bit to show the tapped value as a tooltip.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      behaviors: [
        LinePointHighlighter(
          symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer()  // add this line in behaviours
        )
      ],
      selectionModels: [
        SelectionModelConfig(
          changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            if(model.hasDatumSelection){
              final value = model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index);
              CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.value = value;  // paints the tapped value 
             }
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(1, 25),
      new LinearSales(2, 100),
      new LinearSales(3, 75),
    ];
    return [
      new Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {
static String value;
  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
      fill: Color.white
    );
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(
      TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;
  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated version of the @mahesh-jamdade solution with null safety and upd version paint override method.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as charts_text;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      behaviors: [
        LinePointHighlighter(
          symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer()  // add this line in behaviours
        )
      ],
      selectionModels: [
        SelectionModelConfig(
          changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            if(model.hasDatumSelection){
              final value = model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index);
              CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.value = value.toString();  // paints the tapped value 
             }
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(1, 25),
      new LinearSales(2, 100),
      new LinearSales(3, 75),
    ];
    return [
      new Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {
static String value;
  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int>? dashPattern,
      Color? fillColor,
      FillPatternType? fillPattern,
      Color? strokeColor,
      double? strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds,
        dashPattern: dashPattern,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillPattern: fillPattern,
        strokeColor: strokeColor,
        strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
      fill: Color.white
    );
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(
      charts_text.TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;
  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Comment: Eyyy @Eagle. It sounds interesting. In my case an error appears. Do you know what does it mean? ...

Comment: `'CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.paint' ('void Function(ChartCanvas, Rectangle<num>, {List<int>? dashPattern, Color? fillColor, FillPatternType? fillPattern, Color? strokeColor, double? strokeWidthPx}) (where Color is defined in xxx/painting.dart)') isn't a valid override of 'CircleSymbolRenderer.paint' ('void Function(ChartCanvas, Rectangle<num>, {List<int>? dashPattern, Color? fillColor, FillPatternType? fillPattern, Color? strokeColor, double? strokeWidthPx}) (where Color is defined in xxx/charts_common-0.12.0/lib/src/common/color.dart)').`

Comment: Mmmm.... I fixed it. Since I did `import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;` then I included `charts.Color?` ... in the definition of the Color variables

Answer (score 3):

There were some errors raising when using the above code the modified corrected version of this code is :

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
// import 'package:charts_flutter/src/chart_canvas.dart' as eos;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as TextElement;
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      behaviors: [
        LinePointHighlighter(
          symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer()
        )
      ],
      selectionModels: [
        SelectionModelConfig(
          changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
            if(model.hasDatumSelection)
              print(model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index));
          }
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(1, 25),
      new LinearSales(2, 100),
      new LinearSales(3, 75),
    ];
    return [
      new Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {

  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, FillPatternType fillPattern, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor,fillPattern: fillPattern, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
      fill: Color.white
    );
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(

      TextElement.TextElement("1", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;
  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```