# Error when implementing data tool tips for Chart_Flutter dependencies

Tags: flutter, github, charts, flutter-dependencies

I am currently looking for a solution for tool tip and I found this question on github.

The link is here: https://github.com/google/charts/issues/58

And I wanted to try the implementation by following the github and on StackOverFlow. Here is the answer on stackoverflow: [How show tooltip In Flutter using charts_flutter package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375271/how-show-tooltip-in-flutter-using-charts-flutter-package/64013493#64013493)

Here is how my CustomRender file look like:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
// ignore: implementation_imports
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart';
// ignore: implementation_imports
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_style.dart' as style;

class CustomCircleSymbolRenderer extends CircleSymbolRenderer {
static String value;
  @override
  void paint(ChartCanvas canvas, Rectangle<num> bounds, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx}) {
    super.paint(canvas, bounds, dashPattern: dashPattern, fillColor: fillColor, strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidthPx: strokeWidthPx);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rectangle(bounds.left - 5, bounds.top - 30, bounds.width + 10, bounds.height + 10),
      fill: Color.white
    );
    var textStyle = style.TextStyle();
    textStyle.color = Color.black;
    textStyle.fontSize = 15;
    canvas.drawText(
      TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I have error on this line

```
void paint
```

and here

```
TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
```

Here is what the terminal is saying:

Error number 1:

```
CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.paint' ('void Function(ChartCanvas, Rectangle<num>, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx})') isn't a valid override of 'CircleSymbolRenderer.paint' ('void Function(ChartCanvas, Rectangle<num>, {List<int> dashPattern, Color fillColor, FillPatternType fillPattern, Color strokeColor, double strokeWidthPx
```

Error number 2:

```
TextElement' isn't a function. Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'TextElement'
```

And the last error:

```
The name 'TextElement' is defined in the libraries 'package:charts_common/src/common/text_element.dart' and 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart'. Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need change import from

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart';
```

to

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/src/text_element.dart' as charts_text;
```

And change code from

```
   canvas.drawText(
      TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
```

to

```
  canvas.drawText(
      charts_text.TextElement("$value", style: textStyle),
        (bounds.left).round(),
        (bounds.top - 28).round()
    );
```